# Sales force:How to add data to child object of existing custom object through rest api?

Tags: android, rest, salesforce

I have custom object (My_Custom__c) in sales force store which I insert and update using rest API from android, now there is another custom object (Child__c) which has Master-detail relationship with My_Custom__c.
What is the best way to add data to child object or details object.

I mean how can I do a rest API call for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no different than creating the master object. You would insert it exactly the same way, the only caveat is that the lookup field linking the child to the master must have the Id of the master you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

1) Insert My_Custom__c record
2) get ID of saved record
3) insert Child__c record with above ID in the master-detail field.